# Can't multiply decimal numbers in js

Tags: javascript, html, decimal

I am creating a script that finds the average temperature after the "mixing" of two volumes. The variables are called: `coldWeight` `warmWeight` `coldTemp` `warmTemp`. The formula sounds:

[image]

However, my code here which works as long as I don't use decimal numbers two places.

```
    function averagetemp() {
        let coldWeight = document.getElementById('coldWeight').value;
        let warmWeight = document.getElementById('warmWeight').value;
        let coldTemp = document.getElementById('coldTemp').value;
        let warmTemp = document.getElementById('warmTemp').value;     
        
        var html = (warmWeight *warmTemp +coldWeight *coldTemp )/(coldWeight +warmWeight );   
        var html = html.toFixed(2);
        
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = html;
    }
```

It displays NaN every time I have a decimal number in `coldWeight` and `warmWeight`. None of the others. To compensate for the str to float, I use `step=0.01` in all of the input divs.

Comment: The `.value` property of a DOM node always returns a string. Parse them first into actual numbers -> `parseFloat()`

Comment: The problem is specifically with `coldWeight +warmWeight`: that will *concatenate* two strings instead of adding their values. Change to `+coldWeight + +warmWeight` and you're done.